# Java GeoTools: Creating Shapefile - FeatureCollections deprecated

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools

I'm trying to create & populate Shapefile in Java using GeoTools.

Basically following [this link](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2013/01/java-how-to-convert-csv-to-shapefile-shape-format-shp%E2%80%8E/) (quite similar to the official documentation & other tutorials specifically for the point I'm asking below).

For below code I'm getting first warning that `FeatureCollections` is deprecated and error that `add()` cannot be resolved.

```
FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
...
collection.add(feature);
```

How can I fix that or any other way to create Shapefile using Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefered solution is to use the `gt-csv` datastore to read in the features which will return you a feature collection directly, that you can then write out to a shapefile.

If you really need to do your own parsing the simplest solution is to put the features into a Java collection (e.g. `list`) and then call `DataUtilities.collection(list)` on it.

Or you could use `DefaultFeatureCollection`

```
SimpleFeatureType featureType = DataUtilities.createType(tipoShape,
      "the_geom:" + tipoShape + ":srid=4326," + "number:Integer");

DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", featureType);
```

But make sure to call you geometry column `the_geom` or the Shapefile writer will ignore it.